# DRF - how to 'update' the pk after deleting an object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

a beginner here!

here's how im using url path (from the DRF tutorials):

`path('articles/', views.ArticleList.as_view()),
path('articles/<int:pk>/', views.ArticleDetail.as_view())`

and i noticed that after deleting an 'Article' (**this is my model**), the pk stays the same.

an Example:

```
1st Article pk = 1, 2nd Article pk = 2, 3rd Acrticle pk = 3
```

after deleting the 2n Arctile im **expecting** --

```
1st Article pk = 1, 3rd Artcile pk = 2
```

yet it remains

```
3rd Artile pk = 3.
```

is there a better way to impleten the url, maybe the pk is not the variable im looking for?

or i should update the list somehow?

thnkx

Comment: Why do you expect that? Why is it a problem that there are "gaps" in the sequence? By not updating other primary keys, you save a lot of disk I/O, synchronizing all sorts of tables (which is a serious problem if it is a distributed system), an it has no clear purpose at all.

Comment: This is how RDBMS works, if you delete an object the pk of that is never assigned again. updated my comment thanks to @JonClements

Comment: @danish_wani well... more how RDBMs work :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem not to mention the chaos if you had other tables referencing it for whatever reason and then you end up suddenly re-associating non-related things :)

Comment: hi, im just following the methon in the documents. like i asked, is there a better way to acces different objects via the url?

Comment: @YoavGenish: but I do not follow why this is a bad way in the first place. The fact that `/2` is no longer an object is not a problem. A normal system will return a 404 (or another error for that). In fact not changing the primary key of other objects is better, since it makes it a *permanent* identifier.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i want it to be sorted chronologicly..

Comment: @YoavGenish: primary keys are not even per se sorted chronologically. In fact it is better to see a primary key as a "blackbox". A token that "happens" to be an integer. You can add a timestamp to your models. For popular databases, these are sorted chronologically, these are however not per se *continuous*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there a different method to 'sort' each article?

Answer (score 1):

> and I noticed that after deleting an `Article` (this is my model), the `pk` stays the same.

This is indeed the *expected* behaviour. Removing an object will not "fill the gap" by shifting all the other primary keys. This would mean that for huge tables, you start updating thousands (if not millions) of records, resulting in a huge amount of disk IO. This would make the update (very) slow.

Furthermore not only the primary keys of the table that stores the records should be updated, but all sorts of foreign keys that refer to these records. This thus means that several tables need to be updated. This results in even more disk IO and furthermore it can result in slowing down a lot of unrelated updates to the database due to locking.

This problem can be even more severe if you are working with a *distributed* system where you have multiple databases on different servers. Updating these databases atomically is a serious challenge. The [*CAP theorem* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) demonstrates that in case a network partition failure happens, then you either can not guarantee *availability* or *consistency*. By updating primary keys, you put more "pressure" on this.

Shifting the primary key is also not a good idea anyway. It would mean that if your REST API for example returns the primary key of an object, then the client that wants to access that object might not be able to access that object, because the primary key changed in between. A primary key thus can be seen as a *permanent* identifier. It is usually *not* a good idea to change the token(s) that a client uses to access an object. If you use a primary key, or a slug, you know that if you later refer to the same item, you will again retrieve the same item.

> how to 'update' the pk after deleting an object?

Please **don't**. *Sorting* elements can be done with a timestamp, but that is something different than having an identifier space that does not contain any *gaps*. A *gap* is often not a real problem, so you better do not turn it into a real problem.